# launching multiple nodemon with bashscript

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, shell, nodemon

We are on microservices architecture. I want to switch to different locales of our service using one bash script. I am new to bash and this is my noobish attempt.

```
#!/bin/bash
#RUN THIS COMMAND BEFORE FIRST USE - sudo chmod u+x locale-changer.sh

#DIRECTIONS
#THIS SCRIPT ASSUMES YOU HAVE ALREADY STARTED NPM RUN LOCAL OR REGION=AA DEFAULT_MARKET=PT-BR NODE_ENV=local-qat2 grunt watch
#AFTER STARTING YOUR GRUNT SCRIPT OPEN A NEW TERMINAL TAB AND TYPE IN APPROPRIATE LOCALE NPM SCRIPT EXAMPLE npm run fc TO LAUNCH FRENCH CANADA LOCALE
#PLEASE SEE package.json, FOR LOCALE SPECIFIC SCRIPTS.

# NODEMON=nodemon

# if ! [ -x "$(command -v nodemon)" ]; then
#   echo 'nodemon not installed using node'
#   NODEMON=node
# fi

pid=$(lsof -i tcp:3000 -t); kill -TERM $pid || kill -KILL $pid
pid=$(lsof -i tcp:3001 -t); kill -TERM $pid || kill -KILL $pid
pid=$(lsof -i tcp:3002 -t); kill -TERM $pid || kill -KILL $pid
pid=$(lsof -i tcp:3003 -t); kill -TERM $pid || kill -KILL $pid
pid=$(lsof -i tcp:3004 -t); kill -TERM $pid || kill -KILL $pid
pid=$(lsof -i tcp:3005 -t); kill -TERM $pid || kill -KILL $pid
pid=$(lsof -i tcp:3006 -t); kill -TERM $pid || kill -KILL $pid
pid=$(lsof -i tcp:3008 -t); kill -TERM $pid || kill -KILL $pid

REGION=$1
DEFAULT_MARKET=$2
NODE_ENV=$3

echo "Starting services with REGION=$REGION DEFAULT_MARKET=$DEFAULT_MARKET NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV"
current_dir=$PWD;cd /path/to/your/command/dir;special command ARGS;cd $current_dir;
PORT=3003 REGION=$REGION DEFAULT_MARKET=$DEFAULT_MARKET NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV node ../core-service1/app/server/server.js &
PORT=3002 REGION=$REGION DEFAULT_MARKET=$DEFAULT_MARKET NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV node ../code-service2/app/server/server.js &
PORT=3000 REGION=$REGION DEFAULT_MARKET=$DEFAULT_MARKET NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV nodemon ../router/app/server/server.js &
PORT=3001 REGION=$REGION DEFAULT_MARKET=$DEFAULT_MARKET NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV node ./app/server/server.js &
PORT=3004 REGION=$REGION DEFAULT_MARKET=$DEFAULT_MARKET NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV node ../core-service3/app/server/server.js &
PORT=3005 REGION=$REGION DEFAULT_MARKET=$DEFAULT_MARKET NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV node ../core-service4/app/server/server.js &
PORT=3008 REGION=$REGION DEFAULT_MARKET=$DEFAULT_MARKET NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV nodemon ../core-service5/app/server/server.js

trap "trap - SIGTERM && kill -- -$$" SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
```

The problem is that I want nodemon only to restart the server that it detects changes from. The way things are right now If I change something in one of the server directories, no changes are picked up by nodemon. Only if I change something in the directory where the process was initially launched from, nodemon restarts all the servers simultaneously.

You patience and advice is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you give more details?

Comment: Okay, so our grunt script initially launches all the servers and services with the env variables provided at the time of launching the grunt script. To change locales you have to restart the whole grunt process with new env variables which is very time costly. That is where this script comes into play. It stops just the micro-services and relaunches them with new variables. takes less than 5 secs. The only nice feature I would like to add is that Nodemon works with each of the directories separately. Atm nodemon only look at changes in the main process directory and restarts ALL of the servers

Answer (score -1):

Are you attached to using bash for this? Have you considered gulp or another JS based build tool?

There are libraries that allow you to orchestrate multiple processes, watch for changes etc, without having to reinvent the wheel on this.

Comment: We have grunt. But restarting the script on grunt takes too long because there is a long process to restart the grunt scripts. Tests are needed to be run, the remote repos are to be checked for updated code. Linting, the whole process takes like 1 - 2 min and that takes away from dev time when you have to move between locales.

Comment: I ask because, I'm not exactly clear on why multiple servers are being restarted in the first place if they are all running from their own code.